# How to open this ppt link in my web browser?

Tags: google-chrome

[This is the link.](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/%7Escottf/phys2/chapter16.ppt)

I click on it using my browser (chrome), and nothing happens. Why is that? How can I see its internals?

Comment: Browser may be trying to download it rather than 'read' it, but you may not have downloads allowed from that site.

Comment: @Tetsujin Are you able to access it?

Comment: Yes, on 2 browesers, Safari & Chrome. Safari asks before allowing downloads from any new site. I didn't let it [because I'm not interested in what is in it]. Chrome on the other hand doesn't have such good security, so it just downloaded it - you see the download & resulting file bottom left of the page - https://i.stack.imgur.com/8goZ7.png [If that had since vanished, see Downloads in the 'burger' menu, top right.

Comment: @Tetsujin I was able to access it. I created a snapshot in the wayback machine, and then I was able to download the file from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SuperUser! The link you provided is a download link that refers directly to a file on a server. When I click it, it automatically downloads an old PowerPoint file, but I will not open it on my computer. Probably your browser is not able to show you the contents of the file, and you have no programme that is assigned to the file mime type. In order to view it, you will need either MicroSoft PowerPoint, LibreOffice Impress or anything that handels presentation files.